# update chart data called through ajax via PHP, MySQL

Tags: chart.js

My Chart data is called via ajax from a MySQL Database, when the data in the database is updated the chart does not.

The chart renders correctly, just not updating.

I am new to PHP and chartjs. Any assistance would be great

No matter what I have tried I am unable to get the .update or .destroy to work.

My last attempt to include a button to refresh the data on click failed as well.

My code:
HTML:

```html
<div id="chart-container">
    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <button onclick="data">Refresh</button>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="modules/dashboards/js/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="modules/dashboards/js/Chart.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/dashboards/js/app.js">
</script>
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
               url: "http://localhost/mycharts/api/data.php",
               method: "GET",

               success: function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   var subholding = [];
                   var TotalAccounts = [];

                   for (var i in data) {
                       subholding.push("" + data[i].subholding);
                       TotalAccounts.push(data[i].TotalAccounts);
                   }

                   var chartdata = {
                       labels: subholding,
                       datasets: [
                           {
                               label: 'Total Accounts',
                               backgroundColor: [
                                   "red",
                                   "green",
                                   "blue",
                                   "purple",
                                   "magenta",
                                   "yellow",
                                   "orange",
                                   "black"
                               ],
                               borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                               hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                               hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                               data: TotalAccounts
                           }

                       ]
                   };

                   var ctx = $("#mycanvas");
                   var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                       type: 'bar',
                       data: chartdata
                   });

                   function barGraph() {
                       subholding.push("" + data[i].subholding);
                       TotalAccounts.push(data[i].TotalAccounts);

                       data.update();
                   }
               },
               error: function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
               }
           });
});
```

Expected results: when data in the DB is updated, the chart to update automatically or when page is refreshed / opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can try to put ur ajax code in a setInterval function

```
     setInterval(function(){ 

     //Here

      }, 3000);
```

Edit: i meant setInterval

Comment: sorry for asking is the //here where the line $.ajax starts

Comment: Yes, the 3000 means every 3000 milli seconds (3 seconds) it will send a request to ur database, so every 3 seconds your chart will be refreshed

Comment: Thanks this does work, how ever the rate of refresh has to go between the last set of ending brackets, having this chart update every 3 seconds is a bit much, I have increased the interval to 30 seconds, but now waiting 30 seconds for the initial chart to be rendered

Answer (score 2):

Try this then:

JS

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
           url: "http://localhost/mycharts/api/data.php",
           method: "GET",

           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               var subholding = [];
               var TotalAccounts = [];

               for (var i in data) {
                   subholding.push("" + data[i].subholding);
                   TotalAccounts.push(data[i].TotalAccounts);
               }

               var chartdata = {
                   labels: subholding,
                   datasets: [
                       {
                           label: 'Total Accounts',
                           backgroundColor: [
                               "red",
                               "green",
                               "blue",
                               "purple",
                               "magenta",
                               "yellow",
                               "orange",
                               "black"
                           ],
                           borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                           hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 
                              200, 1)',
                           hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                           data: TotalAccounts
                       }

                   ]
               };

               var ctx = $("#mycanvas");
               var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                   type: 'bar',
                   data: chartdata
               });

               function barGraph() {
                   subholding.push("" + data[i].subholding);
                   TotalAccounts.push(data[i].TotalAccounts);

                   data.update();
               }
           },
           error: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
           }
       });
   });

   setInterval(function(){ 

 $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
           url: "http://localhost/mycharts/api/data.php",
           method: "GET",

           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               var subholding = [];
               var TotalAccounts = [];

               for (var i in data) {
                   subholding.push("" + data[i].subholding);
                   TotalAccounts.push(data[i].TotalAccounts);
               }

               var chartdata = {
                   labels: subholding,
                   datasets: [
                       {
                           label: 'Total Accounts',
                           backgroundColor: [
                               "red",
                               "green",
                               "blue",
                               "purple",
                               "magenta",
                               "yellow",
                               "orange",
                               "black"
                           ],
                           borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                           hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 
                              200, 1)',
                           hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                           data: TotalAccounts
                       }

                   ]
               };

               var ctx = $("#mycanvas");
               var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                   type: 'bar',
                   data: chartdata
               });

               function barGraph() {
                   subholding.push("" + data[i].subholding);
                   TotalAccounts.push(data[i].TotalAccounts);

                   data.update();
               }
           },
           error: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
           }
       });
   });

  }, 30000);
```

Comment: Thanks again, this is working to a point, initial graph loads, after the first interval iteration, the hover tool tips breaks, then the graph disappears after the 2nd interval iteration

Answer (score 1):

I have created a similar approach last year. This has been my simplified approach:

1. initialize the chart with all options
2. Call the Chartrefresh function
3. Trigger the AJAX request with SetTimeout
4. Recall the Chartrefresh function

I hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    Chartrefresh(); 

});

var ctx = $("#mycanvas");
var myChartPF = new Chart(ctx, {

type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: <?php echo json_encode($chartpfscore['data']); ?>,
        labels: <?php echo json_encode($chartpfscore['labels']); ?>,
    },
options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Score ####",
        fontSize: 22,
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'label'
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: '####'
                    }
                }],
        yAxes: [
                      {
                        stacked: false,
                        position: "left",
                        id: "y-axis-0",
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Average Score'
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                stepSize: 5

                            }
                      }, {
                        stacked: false,
                        position: "right",
                        id: "y-axis-1",
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: '###########'
                            },

                             ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                stepSize: 1
                            }
                      }
                ]
    }
}

});

function Chartrefresh()
    {
        // Function to autoupdate Chart

        setTimeout(function()
        {           

                $.ajax({
                    url : "<?php echo site_url('ajax/chartrequest')?>",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                       success: function(newDataObject){

                    myChartPF.data.datasets = newDataObject;
                    window.myChartPF.update(); 
                    Chartrefresh();
                }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

The data from the PHP Controller looks like this (data & labels):

```
[{"data":["58.0000","44.0000","50.6000","49.0000","57.2222","45.6667"],"label":"Average Score","yAxisID":"y-axis-0","backgroundColor":["rgba(222, 30, 101, 0.8)","rgba(171, 158, 153, 0.8)","rgba(125, 94, 166, 0.8)","rgba(228, 110, 23, 0.8)","rgba(21, 62, 140, 0.8)","rgba(241, 214, 31, 0.8)"],"borderWidth":3},{"data":["8","1","5","4","9","3"],"label":"No. Of Resource Schedules","yAxisID":"y-axis-1","borderWidth":3}]


["ProjectA","ProjectB","ProjectC","ProjectD","ProjectE","ProjectF"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Skaw, this has enabled me to get the on page load refresh to chart to work, now to work out why the AJAX timeout function is not working. On inspecting the code it is complaining that my data / datasets are not defined. Any pointers?